# Error 'System.StackOverflowException' in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

How to solve this error?

This is my code

```
public void X()
{
    foreach (char c in txtNumbers.Text)
    {
        sum = sum + (int.Parse(c.ToString()) * int.Parse(c.ToString()));
    }

    txtNumbers.Text = (sum.ToString());
    sum = 0;

    if (txtNumbers.Text == "1")
    {
        Response.Write("happy numbers");
        return;
    } else { 
        X();
    }
}
```

And this is the error...

[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img820/3553/wrzb.jpg]

Comment: sum = sum + (int.Parse(c.ToString()) * int.Parse(c.ToString()));
You might need to declare the sum before using it?

Answer (score 5):

if the numbers don't add up to "1", your program is going to enter into an infinite loop. and crash. hard. like it did.

This is because in your `else` block, you call `X()` method again. And there seems to be no way to stop your recursion and hence your program is crashing.

A simple fix:

```
public void X()
{
        foreach (char c in txtNumbers.Text)
        {
            sum = sum + (int.Parse(c.ToString()) * int.Parse(c.ToString()));
        }

        txtNumbers.Text = (sum.ToString());
        sum = 0;

        if (txtNumbers.Text == "1")
        {
            Response.Write("happy numbers");
            return;
        }else{
             Response.Write("sad numbers");
        }
    }
```

Also, I recommend using `TryParse()` methods, but that's for another season.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is that the `X` method recursively calls itself.  This is the root cause of the stack overflow but it is actually getting triggered on the `int.Parse` call.  You need to change your else logic so that it doesn't keep branching into `X()` without ever terminating

Answer (score 0):

If `txtNumbers.Text` is never `"1"` you will have a recursion that continues until you get the StackOverflowException. Simply because you invoke `X()` when `txtNumbers.Text` is different from `"1"`.